# Parse url to get a string in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a web server sitting behind Nginx. If there is an error, then I want to fetch some information from the url and pass it on to a static file as parameters. I have configured Nginx to fetch the url parameters from the url using $arg_param_name. However, I also need to fetch a String from the url path itself. So if the url is as below:

```
www.website.com/path1/path2?arg1=val&arg2=someval
```

Now, how can I parse this url to fetch the last path (path2 in this case)? My location directive is as below:

```
location ~*/path1/{
   ...
}
```

The url need not always have the same number of paths. It can also have 3 paths. So I can't use $1, $2 etc. I need to fetch the last path, i.e the path which is immediately followed by the url parameters (the ? symbol).